# Building a Ruby calcualtor > Problems with decimals

Tags: ruby, decimal

I'm building a simple calculator in Ruby using Green Shoes, a graphics toolkit. This calculator should work similar to the standard Windows Calculator, with the ability to perform `*/+=` functions on integers and decimals (fractions) and output values rounded to the 100th place.

So far, the calculator can add/subtract/multiply/divide integers and output integers. For example, `6/5=1`, `8/3=2`, and `1/2=0`. The is the first issue, as I want the calculator to output values rounded to the 100th place.

The second issue regards inputs, as calculator does not currently recognize floating points when entering value. This is probably due to the fact that I haven't assigned any variables/functions to my `.` decimal button.

My code is as follows:

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app(title: "Ford's calculator", width: 200, height: 260) do
  number_field = nil
  @number = 0

  flow width: 200, height: 260 do
    flow width: 0.7, height: 0.2 do
      number_field = para @number, margin: 10
    end

    flow width: 0.3, height: 0.2 do
      background rgb(232, 161, 0)

      button 'Clr', width: 1.0, height: 1.0 do
        @number = 0
        number_field.replace(@number)
      end
    end

    flow width: 1.0, height: 0.8 do
      background rgb(50, 205, 50)

      %w(7 8 9 + 4 5 6 - 1 2 3 / 0 . = *).each do |btn|
        button btn, width: 50, height: 50 do
          case btn
            when /[0-9]/
              @number = @number.to_i * 10 + btn.to_i

            when '='
              @number = @previous.send(@op, @number)
            else
              @previous, @number = @number, nil
              @op = btn
          end

          number_field.replace(@number)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So my questions are as follows:

1. What do I need to add to my code to make the app INPUT floating
   points in terms of capturing variables?
2. What do I need to add to my code to make the app OUTPUT numbers
   rounded to the 100th place instead of rounding to whole numbers?
   Thanks in advance! And if there's any clarification you guys need in re: requirements, etc., let me know!

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

To convert a `String` to a `Float`:

```
"3.41".to_f # 3.41
@input = @input.to_f # Convert String @input to a Float
```

To print a number with max x decimals, use `round`:

```
3.412631.round(2) # 3.41
3.412631.round(100) # 3.412631
```